# Cannot ping server after docker run

Tags: docker, vmware, coreos

I'm running docker on coreos vmware. I have an application running node exposing port 3030 and this container has run on my PC fine. I can ping the server (from outside the server) upon startup, but as soon as I run this command I can no longer ping the machine. From what I gather docker places this container on it's own IP? Why would that prevent me from pinging the server? Also I've tried -p 0.0.0.0:3030:3030 as well as the server IP.

```
docker run -d -p 3030:3030 -w=/AppName myrepo/app node bin/www
```

[image]

Essentially I have a node/express app opening my webapp to port 3030 for external traffic.

**UPDATE**: Turns out docker by default assigns a `172.*.*.*` range which is currently being used by our network (maybe not reachable?) I've modified the DOCKER_OPTS to start with `--bip` and assigned an IP. Trying `--fixed-cidr=192.168.0.0/24` still resulted in it assigning a 172 range. I don't understand what implications it has when it assigns an IP since the docker host already has an IP that I'll be connecting to and I connect to each container via port. Is this just an internal IP?

Comment: Try disabling SELINUX and iptables

Comment: How do you disabled iptables? It's not an option under docker run --help anymore

Comment: `sudo service iptables stop`/ `sudo service firewalld stop` in the host VM.

Comment: Also try changing `-p 8080:3030 ` and access your app using <HostIP>:8080. Just to check 3030 port is blocked by firewall/SELinux in your host.

Comment: systemctl stop iptables and systemctl stop firewalld results in "Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded" My unix knowledge is very basic.

By changing the port to 8080 it's still not allowing in traffic and my server doesn't respond to pings.

Comment: fwiw I have a network.static file set up with the IP of the server, wondering if this interferes with Docker's DHCP